# How to get rid of almost identicall rows that are in fact "duplicates", and in fact, only some columns data are switched?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, duplicates, inner-join

I work on database that holds file information. Data are spread across few tables, with data from `File` table, which contains `file_id` there are associated data in other tables such as `disk`, `directory`, `hashes`, etc. My current goal is to be able to find duplicate files based on collected earlier file hash data. Additionaly target is to be able to make query across two databases at once, so query result will include also value indicating source database, in this query these values are dummy and present in result as `org_db` and `fnd_db` as placeholders that, as I guess, their presence is significant in solving my problem so I do mention their existence.

```
SELECT
    A.file_id org_file_id,
    B.file_id fnd_file_id,
    AF.directory_id org_dir_id,
    BF.directory_id fnd_dir_id,
    AD.disk_id org_disk,
    BD.disk_id fnd_disk,
    1 org_db,
    1 fnd_db
FROM fhash A, file AF, file BF, directory AD, directory BD
INNER JOIN fhash B ON B.data = A.data
WHERE
    A.file_id <> B.file_id AND
    A.file_id IN (SELECT _id FROM file WHERE directory_id IN (SELECT _id FROM directory WHERE disk_id <> 0)) AND
    B.file_id IN (SELECT _id FROM file WHERE directory_id IN (SELECT _id FROM directory WHERE disk_id <> 0)) AND
    A.file_id = AF._id AND
    B.file_id = BF._id AND
    AF.directory_id = AD._id AND
    BF.directory_id = BD._id AND
ORDER BY org_file_id


| org_file_id | fnd_file_id | org_dir_id | fnd_dir_id | org_disk | fnd_disk | org_db | fnd_db |
===============================================================================================
| 97          | 118         | 5          | 8          | 2        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 106         | 147         | 8          | 9          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 106         | 175         | 8          | 10         | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 107         | 148         | 8          | 9          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 107         | 176         | 8          | 10         | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 108         | 149         | 8          | 9          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 108         | 177         | 8          | 10         | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 110         | 151         | 8          | 9          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 110         | 179         | 8          | 10         | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
...
| 118         | 97          | 8          | 5          | 3        | 2        | 1      | 1      |
| 147         | 106         | 9          | 8          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 148         | 107         | 9          | 8          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 149         | 108         | 9          | 8          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 151         | 110         | 9          | 8          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 175         | 106         | 10         | 8          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 176         | 107         | 10         | 8          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 177         | 108         | 10         | 8          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
| 179         | 110         | 10         | 8          | 3        | 3        | 1      | 1      |
```

Result I got is fairly good and can be used after further processing but what i'm getting is double what I desire. For each row there is a mirror one, further in table, where in fact each of following four pairs of columns is copy of earlier row with data switched between coresponding columns.

What I'm wondering about is if, and how I could get right result straight from query with  no further processing.

If I would got only two columns and no additional factors like disks, directories and databases fix would be simple as changing

```
    A.file_id <> B.file_id AND
```

to

```
    A.file_id < B.file_id AND
```

Additionaly these lines

```
    A.file_id IN (SELECT _id FROM file WHERE directory_id IN (SELECT _id FROM directory WHERE disk_id <> 0)) AND
    B.file_id IN (SELECT _id FROM file WHERE directory_id IN (SELECT _id FROM directory WHERE disk_id <> 0)) AND
```

are just sample, and depending on search criteria they are changing, these could be as well like

```
    A.file_id IN (SELECT _id FROM file WHERE directory_id IN (SELECT _id FROM directory WHERE disk_id = 0)) AND
    B.file_id IN (SELECT _id FROM file WHERE directory_id IN (SELECT _id FROM directory WHERE disk_id = 0)) AND
```

or

```
    A.file_id IN (SELECT _id FROM file WHERE directory_id IN ([query gets ids of dir  subdirs])) AND
    B.file_id IN (SELECT _id FROM file WHERE directory_id IN (SELECT _id FROM directory WHERE disk_id <> 0)) AND
```

Or in other way. Rest of query stays pretty much unchanged besides further modifications to make it work across two databases.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: @jarlh Can you say something more? SQL is not my everyday thing, i got only basic knowledge.

Comment: Try to simplify the problem - make it easy to assist you! (The less time it takes to read and understand a question, the better answer you will get, and quicker.)

Comment: @jarlh My explanation of problem, for my knowledge and skills (including language skills), is as simple and as detailed as it is required by problem i'm having, most of it is code and example output. If you know better, please be so kind and correct me or give answer or fix my description of problem if it contains logicall errors.

Comment: Are all rows duplicated or there are rows with no duplicate?

Comment: @forpas Sorry, I did missinformed you, it can happen that row have no "duplicate row" at all but in this example above it happens always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sample data I believe that using:

```
GROUP BY MIN(org_file_id, fnd_file_id), MAX(org_file_id, fnd_file_id)
```

where [`MIN()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#min_scalar) and [`MAX()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#max_scalar) are SQLite's scalar functions, will eliminate the duplicates:

```
SELECT A.file_id org_file_id,
       B.file_id fnd_file_id,
       AF.directory_id org_dir_id,
       BF.directory_id fnd_dir_id,
       AD.disk_id org_disk,
       BD.disk_id fnd_disk,
       1 org_db,
       1 fnd_db
FROM fhash A
INNER JOIN file AF ON A.file_id = AF._id
INNER JOIN directory AD ON AF.directory_id = AD._id
INNER JOIN fhash B ON B.data = A.data
INNER JOIN file BF ON B.file_id = BF._id
INNER JOIN directory BD ON BF.directory_id = BD._id
WHERE A.file_id <> B.file_id 
  AND A.file_id IN (SELECT _id FROM file WHERE directory_id IN (SELECT _id FROM directory WHERE disk_id <> 0)) 
  AND B.file_id IN (SELECT _id FROM file WHERE directory_id IN (SELECT _id FROM directory WHERE disk_id <> 0))
GROUP BY MIN(org_file_id, fnd_file_id), MAX(org_file_id, fnd_file_id)
ORDER BY org_file_id;
```

I also changed to proper explicit joins with `ON` clauses.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0702055876113e8ccfb93894471bbdc3).

Comment: Are you certain that your solution is right? And suggested `GROUP BY MIN(org_file_id, fnd_file_id), MAX(org_file_id, fnd_file_id)` will be enough when not only two first columns but also rest of them are significant? As I mentioned, for result `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` if duplicate result which I want to eliminate comes up in results and looks like this: `2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7`. It appears that either i made mistake or your code doesn't work, on my test db i got 70 rows instead of expected 46 from 92 that i get with query from my question.

Comment: @MoreThanChaos you can see in the demo that the result is correct. Also, I mention in my answer: *For this sample data...*. If your data is different then I can't say if it works. I already asked in the comments if all rows are duplicated and you answered yes, but it seems that it should be no. So, if the code does not work in your actual data then your actual data is not as you described them.